# Mobile application development in .Net for all mobile OS

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, mobile

I am c# developer and want to develop one application on all major mobile platforms. I would like to share my business logic via .net services (WCF, REST or WEB.API) to all platforms. Is it possible? If yes then in what major platforms I can use those services? Please suggest, what kind of application architecture should I use?

Let me clarify it.
Can I use .net services (WCF, REST or WEB.API) in android and ios mobile phone app?

Comment: I must really be missing something, if you business logic is all in REST services, this is by definitely about as cross platform as it could be. As far as you architecture is concerned, that should depend on your requirements (and budget). I see someone has already recommended phonegap and jquery mobile as I was typing (and they are quite useful). Still, you have not even specified native app vs web app vs hybrid app, so it is not possible to answer your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into phone gap http://phonegap.com/ and jquery mobile http://jquerymobile.com/. I have only used jquery mobile but made a web app with a .net service to get data. Then you use the jquery mobile to display it on the different mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: http://xamarin.com/

Its a C# framework for developing Cross-Platform Mobile Apps.

Comment: It's worth noting this would cost at least $2000/year to use.